# Active Directory authentication with Codeigniter Library

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, codeigniter-2

I am using the ldap library for Codeigniter written by Greg Wojtak from [auth_ldap_library](http://www.techrockdo.com/projects/auth_ldap).

I have setup the config as per the instructions. However when i try to authenticate using my username and password i am getting an error (ldap_bind() unable to bind).

Below is the config

```
$config['ldap_uri'] = array('ldaps://dc1.mycompany.com/', 'ldaps://dc2.mycompany.com/');
$config['use_tls'] = false;  // Using SSL above, don't use TLS with it
$config['search_base'] = 'DC=mycompany,DC=com';
$config['user_search_base'] = 'CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com';
$config['group_search_base'] = 'CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com';
$config['user_object_class'] = 'user';
$config['group_object_class'] = 'group';
$config['user_search_filter'] = '';
$config['group_search_filter'] = '';
$config['login_attribute'] = 'sAMAccountName';
$config['schema_type'] = 'ad'; // Could also use rfc2307bis
$config['proxy_user'] = '';  // Or CN=ProxyUser,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=com
$config['proxy_pass'] = '';
$config['roles'] = array(1 => 'User', 
                    3 => 'Power User',
                    5 => 'Administrator');
$config['auditlog'] = 'application/logs/audit.log';
```

This is the line where iam getting the error "error looking up DN for username"

line 217 is the foreach line

```
   foreach($this->user_search_base as $usb) {
   $search = ldap_search($this->ldapconn, $usb, $filter, 
            array('dn', $this->login_attribute, 'cn'));
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($this->ldapconn, $search);
        if(isset($entries[0]['dn'])) {
            $binddn = $entries[0]['dn'];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Error message is as below.

[image: Error Message]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: If you can post some code and config we'll have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: updated the question with code @DazzKnowles